# Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in manifest file using asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

i am trying to use asset pipeline and want to have more then one manifest file. At present i have application.css manifest file and admin_area.css manifest file. One of the stack answer suggested to remove application.css manifest, however it will not solve my intent.

Current Error msg:

Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Authenticate#dashboard
projectfolder/app/assets/stylesheets/admin_area.css has already been required

My current rails version is : 4.1.5

And also please suggest solution to have more then one javascript manifest file.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `require_tree .` directive in both your manifests - one of them tries to require another manifests, and another will try to require first, and it leads to circular error.

Instead you should explicitly require assets in your manifests.

Comment: Got following error after removing require_tree and was able to fix it as per the suggestion: 
"Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin_area.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server"

-thank @MikDiet

Answer (score 1):

**`Manifest file:`** If you look at [`docs`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives), it says

> Sprockets uses manifest files to determine which assets to include and serve. These manifest files contain directives - instructions that tell Sprockets which files to require in order to build a single CSS or JavaScript file

*so in short rails asset pipeline precompile your all of your **assets like css,js in single file(one file for all of your css files and one js file for all of your js).** By doing this **load time of your pages is significantly reduced** because your browser makes fewer requests to get these files individually.*

**Having More than one manifest files:**

*In some cases like in your case or if you are making **your app compatible with <= IE8 then you might want to have more than one manifest files as IE only allows a some fixed size of your styles** and ignore your other styles*

To achieve this you follow these steps:

a. ***Remove require_tree .*** from your application.css file because it will require all of your styles present in app/assets/stylesheets and hence you should require each file individually.

b. ***In case of [`Production`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) you need to precompile your assets*** and for that you'll have to add your individual files by

```
#config/application.rb or config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin_area.css', 'other.css', 'some_file.js']
```

**Your error:**

> Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Authenticate#dashboard projectfolder/app/assets/stylesheets/admin_area.css has already been required

***Your error clearly says you have a circular dependency meaning one of your files is trying to load resources of other and other one is trying to load resources of first one making a circular dependency***. As `@MikDiet` already mentioned in his answer that you ***have `require_tree .` in both of your css files.***